# Geeting results from multipe(4) tables joins using SQL or code if needed (python)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, join

I'm working with PostgreSQL 10 and Python 3. I know how to o simple selects or joins, buy I have issues when need to combine 4 tables related 2 by 2.

I mention, that I use Phyton, in case is necessary to combine queries using code.

I have the following tables: Company, CompanyLogo, Product, ProductImage, with the following

1. Relations:

   - Company Logo O1O with Company
   - Product has FK to Company
   - ProductImage FK with Product
2. Structure

   ```
   Company

   Id  | slug
    1     1
   ```

---

```
    Logo
    Id | path | company_id
    1     url        1


   -----------
    Product
    Id | company_id
    1     1
    2     1


    ProductImage

    Id | path | product_id
    1     url   1
    2     url   1 
    3     url   1
```

I need:

1. Get list of all companies, and for each company get:

   - the company slug
   - the logo
   - up to 3 products and their first image
2. Get one company based on id and:

   - the company slug
   - the logo
   - all product and their first image

Comment: What is got to do with python?

Comment: @KaushikNayak  If it needs separate queries to combine them using code; for speed consideration or if is not possible only with SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that you have this restrictions for the numbers of products or images.

I tried to solve this in subqueries selecting only the first *n* products/pictures per company/product by determining the count of lower IDs. An ID only matches if there are no more than *n* IDs less or equal the ID for the same company or product. In other words the products/images with the *n* (or less than *n*, if there aren't more) lowest IDs per company/product will make it in the result. For `logo`, if I got you right, `company_id` is unique, so that step isn't needed there. (In case I misunderstood that, It'd be a subquery analog to the others.) In case of pictures that indeed fetches the *first* picture, given that the ID is automatically incremented. So if "first" in your question had to be taken literally, that's given too.

I assumed you want to see a company/product even, if there is no logo/product/picture for it. So I used `LEFT JOIN`s.

1. Two sub queries, one for `product`, one for `productimage`:

   ```
   SELECT c.id,
          c.slug,
          l.id,
          l.path,
          p.id,
          i.id,
          i.url
          FROM company c
               LEFT JOIN logo l
                         ON l.company_id = c.id
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT pi.id,
                                 pi.company_id
                                 FROM product pi
                                 WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                                               FROM product pii
                                               WHERE pii.company_id = pi.company_id
                                                     AND pii.id <= pi.id) <= 3) p
                         ON p.company_id = c.id
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id,
                                 i.product_id,
                                 i.path
                                 FROM productimage ii
                                 WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                                               FROM productimage iii
                                               WHERE iii.product_id = ii.product_id
                                                     AND iii.id <= ii.id) <= 1) i
                         ON i.product_id = p.id;
   ```
2. One subquery for `productimage`; replace the `?` with the respective company ID:

   ```
   SELECT c.id,
          c.slug,
          l.id,
          l.path,
          p.id,
          i.id,
          i.url
          FROM company c
               LEFT JOIN logo l
                         ON l.company_id = c.id
               LEFT JOIN product p
                         ON p.company_id = c.id
               LEFT JOIN (SELECT i.id,
                                 i.product_id,
                                 i.path
                                 FROM productimage ii
                                 WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                                               FROM productimage iii
                                               WHERE iii.product_id = ii.product_id
                                                     AND iii.id <= ii.id) <= 1) i
                         ON i.product_id = p.id
          WHERE company_id = ?;
   ```

(Untested, as no DDL or DML was provided.)